# Trying to find substring of string that equals "\" in javascript

Tags: javascript, backslash

What I'm trying to do is compare the order of backslashes in 2 texts (one is English text, the other is user inputted translated text).
I first do an if statement to make sure both texts have backslashes and then create separate lists for the two texts in order to compare the order.
NOTE: if sourcetext has a backslash, in dev tools, it does show as "\".

But even though I know there's a backslash at a specific index, my code isn't placing that sourcetext.substring(w+1, 1) into my tokenlist...
Not sure where to fix my bug and/or why it's not recognizing the comparison of the substring and "\".
The output I want from the tokenlist is:

```
tokenlist = "\\n\\n\\t";
```

But instead I get nothing put into tokenlist.
Any insight would be appreciated!

```js
var sourcetext = "Example \n\t\n";
var newtext = "Exemple \n\t\n";

if (newtext.includes('\\') && sourcetext.includes('\\')) {
  var tokenlist = "";
  var tokenlisttran = "";

  for (let w = 0; w < sourcetext.length - 1; w++) {
    if (sourcetext.substring(w, 1) == "\\") {
      tokenlist += "\\" + sourcetext.substring(w + 1, 1);
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < newtext.length - 1; i++) {
    if (newtext.substring(i, 1) == "\\") {
      tokenlisttran += "\\" + newtext.substring(i + 1, 1);
    }
  }
}

console.log(tokenlist,tokenlisttran)
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: [You likely need \\\ or \\\\ to find more than one backslash](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+find+backslash+in+string+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: An example of your input and expected output would go a long way to clarify your question. Seems regex might be a good option.

Comment: Just edited..Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @mplungja, I tried \\\ and \\\\ and that didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: There are two problems in the code: 1) Your input strings don't contain backslashes, but instead tab stops (ASCII 9) and "line feed" (ASCII 10). 2) The function `substring(start, end)` expects start- and end-index. Use `substr(start, length)` instead.

Comment: Changing substring(start, end) to the substr(start, length) was the answer to making this work. Thank you!